# hazelcast map-reduce use only one cpu core

Tags: multithreading, mapreduce, hazelcast, infinispan

I run a map-reduce job on a single-node hazelcast cluster and it consumes only about one CPU (120-130%). I can't find how to configure hazelcast to eat all available CPU up, is it possible at all?

EDIT:
While Hazelcast does not support in-node parallelism another competing opensource in-memory datagrid (IMDG) solution does - Infinispan. See [this article](http://blog.infinispan.org/2014/07/upcoming-infinispan-700-mapreduce-is.html) to learn more about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation of Mapping and Reducing is single threaded. Hazelcast is not meant to run as a single node environment and the map-reduce framework is designed in a way to support scale-out and not exhaust the whole CPU. You can start up multiple nodes on your machine to parallelize processing and utilize the CPU that way but it seems to me that you might use Hazelcast for a problem that it is not meant to solve. Can you elaborate your use case?

Comment: Yes I could run several instances on a host, but performance gain is not so good as I expect (far from linear). I actually build a system that run analytical queries upon a dataset of several GBs, I could do it in memory without Hazelcast on a single machine, but I use Hazelcast to make sure, that if there will be not enough RAM/CPU on a single host it can scale out. Cause there will be just a few users I don't mind if Hazelcast make use of all CPU of a dedicated cluster.

Comment: I am surprised, that Hazelcast, claiming to be general-purpose distributed computing engine, doesn't have this basic feature :( For example, when starting a Spark job you can adjust how many cores it will use.

Comment: It will be added over time but parallelizing a mapreduce operation and let it really run in parallel not just linear one phase after another is really hard and complex. If you look at the documentation there is a paragraph about this complexity and it is still hard to understand when is what running where.
Currently this is the design decision, just as you learn it - if you can't make it run single-threaded don't try it multithreaded. The future will use multiple mappers to parallelize the processing of multiple partitions at once but that means you have again different things you need to

Comment: think about while implementing your mapper. You either would need multiple instances or every mapper needs to be context free which is not always the case. It already never is for Combiners and Reducers.
About linear scaling: It won't just never happen, you have coordination and data transmission between nodes which add overhead. Mapreduce was never designed to be the fastest solution but the best parallelizable one - if that makes sense :)

Comment: IMHO from a theoretical view if map-reduce is a parallel algorithm that runs nicely among nodes (that share no state between each other!) it would be not so difficult to gain parallelism among threads in one node too (just treating one node as several ones). Can we run mappers in parallel? Yes. Can we run several combiners in parallel (of course, it will add some network overhead )? Yes. Though it adds some implementation complexity, but from a user's view it's quite the same. Context-free requirement seems to be natural, cause map-reduce is a functional data transformation only.

Comment: Saying about far-from-linear performance gain I meant that case when I run several Hazelcast instances on one host, not map-reduce itself. Running on my 4-core PC 4 instances I see it runs only about 2 times faster comparing to one node performance, so overhead takes 50% that's too much.

Comment: I guess this heavily depends on the use case, do you have a test case to show this extremely low improvement over a single node?

Comment: My case was counting distribution on a map with 500 k entries, that has as a value another map <String, Integer> with 100 entries (features and their values). I counted distribution for all 100 features in one go. I didn't persist code for that.

Comment: If you are interested you can have a look on the code I was running.
https://gist.github.com/MikhailGolubtsov/2cca99f57392e5397d23